# PHP CLI on OSX ignores php.ini settings

Tags: php, macos, command-line-interface, memory-limit

PHP CLI on my Mac OSX ignores memory_limit settings.
I located php.ini using

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Then I fixed it:

```
memory_limit = 1024M
```

I even restarted Apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

But still when I run

```
php -i | grep memory_limit
```

I get

```
memory_limit => 256M => 256M
```

What could it be?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Look for `Loaded Configuration File` that will tell you the `php.ini` it actually loads

Comment: `Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini`

I edited exactly this file, but nothing happens.

Comment: Oh by the way, as you are using CLI (Command Line Interface) restarting Apache is not necessary as it is not involved

Comment: Let's start at the beginning. What probelm are you trying to fix by increasing the `memory_limit` and show any errors that made you think that upping this would help

Comment: It's a very common problem with insufficient memory for composer.  Now I run it with -d option. For example: 
    `php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer install`
But I'd like to run it without this "dancing with a tambourine" :)

Answer (score 10):

If you run this command

```
php --info | grep additional
```

You may see a result like this:

```
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/php5/php.d
```

This indicates that your PHP installation is also scanning an additional folder of .ini files that will augment your configuration - usually these are for extensions but any of these can override the settings that are in your loaded php.ini file. Check whether these are overriding your memory_limit:

```
cd /usr/local/php5/php.d
grep memory_limit *
```

In my case I had a developer extensions file that was resetting the memory_limit to 256M, which meant that making changes in php.ini had no effect. Perhaps this is the issue you're having.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for ages, and FINALLY found this to be the issue so thank you! There was some 99-liip-developer.ini file overriding things.

Answer (score 0):

CLI PHP may not be using the same php.ini as Apache uses, but you can specify which to use at command line..

```
php -c path/to/php.ini>|/path/to/php-file-to-run.php
```

Comment: I really think we covered that in the comments

Comment: well then, that's not an answer..  I'm just trying to give a work around eg; specifying which php.ini to use

Answer (score 0):

Try to find on this file:

```
/usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini # in my case 99- but i think it could be another number
```

and set this:

```
memory_limit = -1 #or another value to specify the limit Ex: 521M
```